# How do I get the handle for locking a file in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, locking

The [LockFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365202(VS.85).aspx) API takes a file handle. I normally use TStream for file access, so I'm unsure how to get the appropriate handle, given an ANSIString filename only. My purpose is to lock a file (which may not exist originally) during a process, write some information to other users, and then unlock and delete it.

I would appreciate sample code or pointers to it to make this reliable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the **LockFile** function  in conjunction with [**CreateFile**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28VS.85%29.aspx) and **[UnlockFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365715%28VS.85%29.aspx)** functions.

See this example

```
procedure TFrmMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  aHandle     : THandle;
  aFileSize   : Integer;
  aFileName   : String;
begin
    aFileName    :='C:\myfolder\myfile.ext';
    aHandle      := CreateFile(PChar(aFileName),GENERIC_READ, 0, nil, OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0); // get the handle of the file
    try
        aFileSize   := GetFileSize(aHandle,nil); //get the file size for use in the  lockfile function
        Win32Check(LockFile(aHandle,0,0,aFileSize,0)); //lock the file
        //your code
        //
        //
        //
        Win32Check(UnlockFile(aHandle,0,0,aFileSize,0));//unlock the file
    finally
    CloseHandle(aHandle);//Close the handle of the file.
    end;

end;
```

Another option , if you want to lock the file using TFileStream you can  opening the file using exclusive access (fmShareExclusive).

```
Var
MyStream :TFilestream;
begin
  MyStream := TFilestream.Create( aFileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareExclusive ); 

end;
```

**Note** : in both examples the access is read-only, you must change the flags in order to write the files.

Answer (score 6):

It's pretty simple, actually.  TFileStream has a Handle property that gives you the Windows handle to the file.  And if you're using some other type of stream, there's no underlying file to work with.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to create a file stream with exclusive read/write access:

```
fMask := fmOpenReadWrite or fmShareExclusive;
if not FileExists(Filename) then
  fMask := fMask or fmCreate;
fstm := tFileStream.Create(Filename,fMask);
```

Comment: That isn't quite the same as a lock though is it? And is it safe over a network to a shared drive? I have to be able to guarantee it as much as sensibly possible.

Comment: Okay, I've read the source, and it does end up at a lock call, so it is good.

Answer (score 0):

you can find a complete sample to use **LockFile** API [here](http://neftali.clubdelphi.com/?p=172).
It's used to detect computer in use insede a network. It's compiled in Delphi 6 and source is included.

Excuse-me for my bad english.

Regards.

Comment: This's the old server; You can find the file here:
http://neftali.clubdelphi.com/?p=172

I have updated the link. Thanks.